# Retrieving text between <br> in Rails + Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

For the following partial HTML, I 'm trying to retrieve the text "Conducts research ... find cures!" between two `<br>` tags via Nokogiri.

```
<b>Multiple Sclerosis National Research Institute</b><br>
<!-- <b>CFC Code: 12135</b><br />     ***** This is edited by Anas -->
<a href="http://www.ms-research.org" target="_blank">http://www.ms-research.org</a><br> 
(866)-676-7400<br> 
Conducts research towards understanding, treating and halting the progression of multiple sclerosis and related diseases. Current research progress is promising. Please help us find cures!<br>
<a href="/ntn/charities/view.aspx?record_id=510">Click here for more info</a><br><br>
```

So far, I've been able to retrieve the `name` and `url` with this code:

```
url = "https://www.neighbortonation.org/ntn/charities/home.aspx"    
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css("#site-pagecontent table table td").each do |item|
    name = item.at_css("b").text unless item.at_css("b").blank?
    url = item.at_css("a")[:href] unless item.at_css("a").blank?
end
```

But I got stuck trying to retrieve the text between the specific `<br>` tags. I tried the suggestions via [Extracting between <br> tags with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205082/extracting-between-br-tags-with-nokogiri) but that didn't seems to work. Any ideas? Should I be using xpath, search, or regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
html = '<b>Multiple Sclerosis National Research Institute</b><br> ...'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.css('br')[2].next.text.strip
#=> "Conducts research towards understanding, treating and halting the progression of multiple sclerosis and related diseases. Current research progress is promising. Please help us find cures!"
```

And with the live content:

```
url = "https://www.neighbortonation.org/ntn/charities/home.aspx"    
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css("#site-pagecontent table table td").each do |item|
  description = item.css('br')[2].next.text.strip unless item.css('br').empty?
  ...
end
```

Comment: Works wonders! Thanks. Can you explain to me what this does? I'm not familiar with how map works.

Comment: `Array#map` iterates through the array, yielding each value to the block and creating a new array. Whatever the block returns is used as a "replacement" item for that value. In this case, `&:next` is the same as `{ |item| item.next }`; it creates a block that invokes the `next` method on the value of the array and evaluates to the result. So, decoded the answer above says "Find all the `<br>` as an array, and then replace each with [the `next` item](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next). Now find the third one of those, and get the text, and strip off outside whitespace.

Comment: A couple suggestions: 1) Picking the third `<br>` may work for this particular text snippet, but it seems terribly fragile. I prefer to try to anchor based on solid content (see my answer). 2) Instead of finding all `doc.css('br').map(&:next)[2].text` I suggest the simpler and more-efficient `doc.css('br')[2].next.text`. There's no reason to find the `next` of all the `<br>` that you ultimately do not care about.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks for the suggestions! I was also worried about the fragility of selecting the second element, but I tested it on the link and it worked so I figured it would do. Thanks also for the second suggestion, which I agree with and have incorporated.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense now. I think Nokogiri documentation can use some help though.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about "text between elements" in XML, it helps to remember that text in XML is held in a [Text node](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1312295772). In Nokogiri, this is a [`Nokogiri::XML::Text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html) instance.

For example, this HTML:

```html
<p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p>
```

Is most simply represented by:

```
(Element name:"p" children:[
  (Text content:"Hello ")
  (Element name:"b" children:[
    (Text content:"World")
  ])
  (Text content:"!")
])
```

The `<p>` element has three child nodes. Often we don't need to remember this, because we are often wondering about the text that is a child or descendant, finding an element and then using the [`.text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text) method to give us a string back.

In your case, you want to find the most reliable way of locating a nearby element. Let's assume that the `<a href="...">Click here for more info</a>` will always be present, and the text you want immediately precedes that.

```ruby
# Find an <a> element with specific text content
info = doc.at_xpath('//a[.="Click here for more info"]')

# Walk back to the previous element, which we assume is an always-present <br>
br   = info.previous_element

# Find the Text node immediately preceding that, and then get its contents
desc = br.previous.text
```

We can do this more efficiently and tersely with XPath, but it becomes harder for a Ruby programmer to understand:

```
p doc.at('//a[.="Click here for more info"]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]').text
#=> " \nConducts research towards understanding, treating and halting the ...
```

The above finds the anchor, then uses XPath to find all preceding text nodes, and then selects just the first text node.